# Working with mp3 files in c++

Tags: c++, audio, mp3

I would like to be able to load an .mp3 file into a buffer. Play it from the buffer, pause, stop, and very important I need to be able to play from a specific time within the audio file. I would like to stay away from 3rd party libraries and not have to worry about dependencies and later builds. I am using windows7 64bit with VS2012 c++. Is there any basic built in windows libraries I can link to other then using Direct Sound or OpenAL - Ogg/Vorbis?

```
class AudioStream {
private:
    // Member Variables Here
    std::string m_strFilename;
    std::shared_ptr<SomeBuffer>   m_pAudioBuffer; // This may or may not be needed.

    __int64 m_i64CurrentPlayTime;
    __int64 m_i64TimeSaved;

public:
    // Constructor & Destructor
    AudioStream();
    ~AudioStream();

    // Public Methods
    bool    load( const std::string filename );
    bool    play();
    bool    pause();
    bool    stop();

    // The Variable for this function could be a long or a __int64 not sure yet
    bool    playFrom( __int64& i64TimeToPlayFrom );

 private:
    AudioStream( const AudioStream& c ); // Not Implemented
    AudioStream& operator=( const AudioStream& c ); // Not Implemented

    // If Needed 
    bool    encode();
    bool    decode();
    void    convert(); 

}; // AudioStream
```

I am not sure what to use for reading and playing .mp3 files and how to seek to the correct time for the playFrom method.

Comment: `I would like to take a different approach` Why?

Comment: This is a huge wall of conversational text. Can you trim your post into a more obvious question please?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Learning experience, getting to know multiple sources, improving my programming skills. And for this I do not need anything robust, I just need to load the .mp3 file into a buffer, play it, pause it, stop it, and play it from a specified time. I have a small written library for OggVorbis however the files in this project are all .mp3 and I do not want to convert them since there are about 30 or so files that belong to one object. I do no need Direct Sound since it should just be simple playback from a buffer.

Comment: @As another note, I am not worried too much about codecs or the compression or decompression of the audio files. Most of the .mp3 files being loaded in are not music files, but are merely voice or spoken words.

Comment: "I need to be able to play from a specific time within the audio file" This could be a challenge depending on your needs. Advancing to a specific, sample-accurate location in MP3 is very expensive.

Comment: Don't know much about mp3 in C++, but after researching a bit. I'm guessing its probably easier to batch convert them to a more open format such as ogg vorbis or even non-compressed wav/aif. From what I can find it seems direct sound is the preferred way to do it if you want to use a windows api. And LAME seems a pretty easy lib to use if you do choose to go the 3rd party way afterall :)

Comment: Hmm thank you for the feedback. I might then have to find an audio converter and convert the files to an .ogg file  and use my ogg library. The only thing is I would have to go back through their documentation to find out how to play from a specific time. The library I have for Ogg/Vorbis only plays, pause and stops audio and it is designed for 3D audio in 3D Game Engine applications. It has other features that I do not need such as attaching to a 3D object and a listener. I just wanted simple playback.